# How to set the data type for a route param in swagger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, nestjs

I have a simple nest.js controller with a route param:

```
@Get(':id')
getHello(@Param('id', MyStringPipe) myString: MyString): string {
  return myString.toString();
}
```

The data type of the param is transformed from `string` to `MyString` with a simple `pipe`:

```
export class MyStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    return new MyString(value);
  }
}
```

Now, when I want to try the route with swagger-ui, it rejects a string param:

[image]

How can I set the datatype of the param to `string` for swagger?

---

Try it out here:

[image: Edit nest-swagger-ui-param-type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the type of a param with the `@ApiImplicitParam` decorator:

```
import { ApiImplicitParam } from '@nestjs/swagger';

@Get(':id')
@ApiImplicitParam({ name: 'id', type: String })
getHello(@Param('id', MyStringPipe) myString: MyString): string {
  return myString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import [ApiParam](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.X/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html) from Swagger:

- `nestjs` v8.2.6
- `@nestjs/swagger` v5.2.0

Code:

```
import { ApiParam } from '@nestjs/swagger';

@Get(':id')
@ApiParam({ name: 'id', type: String })
getHello(@Param('id', MyStringPipe) myString: MyString): string {
  return myString.toString();
}
```